# App crashes returning from PhotoChooserTask

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

App crashes when I return from selecting a photo from gallery using

```
PhotoChooserTask photo = new PhotoChooserTask();
photo.Show();
photo.ShowCamera = true;
photo.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photo_Completed);
```

I get a `NullReferencePointer` error from trying to retrieve an object from IsolatedStorage

```
 //GET DATA FROM STORE
    public static object GetDataFromStore(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            if (settings.Contains(key))
            {
                var results = settings[key];
                
                return results;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

private void SetupProfileData()
    {
        //SET DATA
        UserModel model = (UserModel)Utilities.GetDataFromStore(Constants.STORAGE_NAME);
      
            FirstNameTextBox.Text = model.firstname;  //error here on debug
            LastNameTextBox.Text = model.lastname;
            EmailTextBox.Text = model.email;
            AddressTextBox.Text = model.address;
            TelephoneTextBox.Text = model.telephone;

    }
```

On first launch it works properly and correctly fills out the TextBoxes, however after attempting to select a photo I get an error on the line I commented above. The method is called in the `OnNavigatedTo` method of the page like this

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        SetupProfileData();
    }
```

I really do not see why it should be crashing since it does work on first launch, or am I missing some underlying conditions about leaving an app and restoring it? I am working with WP7.

## Edited

Added the method that returns the storage data, an object is stored every time the app is launched. I have put a null check after retrieving the storage data to show a `MessageBox` if `model` is null and after opening the page the first time then staarting the `PhotoChooserTask` and selecting a photo going back to the app `model` then becomes null.

Comment: It's going to be hard telling what's going on without seeing the contents of your `Utilities.GetDataFromStore` method

Comment: Oops, your right i will update my post

Comment: @KooKiz updated, as well as with further debugging it seems that after starting the `PhotoChooserTask` the storage is deleted or replaced is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Apparently, there's something wrong when saving your object to the isolated storage. Make sure you've added the `[DataContract]` attribute to your `UserModel` object, that's the most common mistake

Comment: Matter of fact i didnt, but when i try to add that i get a red underline [DataContract]

Comment: Don't forget to add `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` at the top of your file. Also, make sure to mark each property of your object with the `[DataMember]` attribute or they won't be persisted

Comment: Oops, im such a noob. I will try this now

Comment: I did add the using statement but I still have errors when trying to add the attributes